# How To Verify Disk Integrity of an NFS Share?

Tags: nfs

How can I verify disk integrity of an NFS Share?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't - you verify the disks directly on the machine that's exporting the share.

There's no mechanism for passing disk configuration or geometry, much less disk health, through the NFS protocol.